# How to add jQuery DataTable in this Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

Is it possible to add the following jQuery DataTable?

```
$('#myDataTable').dataTable({

    });
```

to this query?

```
 $(document).on('click', '#PlayStatisticeight', function (e) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("_PartialViewTopPlayedTracksList", "ReportStatistic")',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#PartialViewTopPlayedTracksList").empty();
            $("#PartialViewTopPlayedTracksList").append(data);

            $('#myDataTable').dataTable({

            });


            $(function () {
                $("#PartialViewTopPlayedTracksList").load('@Url.Action("_PartialViewTopPlayedTracksList", "ReportStatistic")');
            });

        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, exceptionThrown) {

            var json = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);

            if (json.Authenticated) {
                window.location.href = '/UnAuthorizedUser/UnAuthorizedUser';
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = '/UnAuthenticatedUser/UnAuthenticatedUser';
            }
        }
    });

 });
```

I don't know how and if it is possible to do so? any help is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just call it once the new partial has been added to the DOM, in the success callback function.

```
        success: function (data) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("_PartialViewTopPlayedTracksList", "ReportStatistic")',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#PartialViewTopPlayedTracksList").empty();
                    $("#PartialViewTopPlayedTracksList").append(data);
            });

    },
```

Comment: This likely won't work, as there won't be anything to apply dataTable to until the _PartialViewTopPlayedTracksList Action loads.  He'll need to do a $.get() for _PartialViewTopPlayedTracksList and then apply the dataTable in the success function for that.

Comment: @Justin Thanks :) I tried it, but it didn't show the DataTable and stopped other queries from working.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks :) - How can I do that? Sorry I am not very familier with jQuery.

Comment: @pv619, Dave has spotted it, see my updates above, this loads using a GET and appends the result.

Comment: @JustinHarvey - Thanks for taking time to edit the code. I have updated my initial code with the new one. All the queries are working now but the DataTable is not showing up.

Comment: thanks Justin and Dave - it's working now. Linking the jQuery libraries was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can initialize datatable, after the partialview is appended on the view in the ajax call complete function like this:

```
success: function (data) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("_PartialViewTopPlayedTracksList", "ReportStatistic")',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#PartialViewTopPlayedTracksList").empty();
                    $("#PartialViewTopPlayedTracksList").append(data);

                    $('#myDataTable').dataTable({ });
            });

    }
```

Comment: thanks :) it worked very much, but after final testing - the query stops other queries from working. i.e. I am also using jTables. Any suggestion? :)

Comment: if these plugins are applied on the partial view html that is rendered dynamically, you need to initialize that plugin as well after the ajax call succes